# How to find items with a given phrase in the list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of certain expressions and I need to draw from it those that contain the phrase '2008'.

[' "test"', ' "bla bla 2009 bla bla"', ' "bla bla 2008 bla bla"']

I need to get in some variable the index numbers of all elements of the list with the phrase '2008'. In the given example it will be 3 element.

Answer (score 1):

This does the job. It simply uses a `for` loop with the [in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) keyword.

```
l = [' "test"', ' "bla bla 2009 bla bla"', ' "bla bla 2008 bla bla"']
index_list = []
for i in range(len(l)):
  if "2008" in l[i]:
    index_list.append(i)
```

Output:

```
print(index_list) # prints '[2]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
l = [ "test",  "bla bla 2009 bla bla",  "bla bla 2008 bla bla"]
items = [elem for elem in l if '2008' in elem]
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if '2008' in l]
# before: indices = [l.index(item) for item in items]
print(indices) # [2]
```

The indices are fetched using *index* method for lists.

Comment: But this does not work if the items in the list are duplicated. ['bla bla 2009 bla', 'papap2009ok', 'kwus2009', 'bla bl4454554a 2009 bla', 'papap2009ok']
[2, 3, 4, 7, 3]

Comment: True, then I would change definition of indices to

    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if '2008' in l]